# Trying to Migrate project from BuildForge to Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, groovy, migration, buildforge

I have to migrate a project from Build-Forge to Jenkins.

As a project can be created in Jenkins from `config.xml` using `Jenkins CLI`. Here, I am trying to build a `config.xml` using `Groovy scripts` accessing the data of the `Build-forge project`. But I am new to Build-forge. So I don't know whether Build-forge stores the project configurations in any file  and it can be accessed or not. I don't know whether my approach is correct or not. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can export the project by executing command ".export". It will save the project into an xml.

You can also use buildforge apis.

Comment: can you be more elaborate please? Where should i run the command